# Web app with persistant user data stored locally

Tags: python, database, django, web-applications

I am wanting to make a web app that allows users to input personal data , keep records and process that data. I don't really want to store each users data on my own server space , I dont want to be responsible for it's security or pay for the space that many users data may end up using. Is it possible to have the web app interface store and interact with the user data on their local machine?

I am using python and learning django.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Comment: This is pretty cool. However I was looking for a solution that could store and retrieve data from a local file. That way the data could be easily backed up (to dropbox for example). I get the feeling that with this HTML5 local storage, if someone cleared their browser caches then all of their data they saved from my app would do down the toilet.